# How to retrieve XML attributes with XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, linq-to-xml

I have this simple XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Artists>
 <artist artistId="1">
<name>ManyBass</name>
<genre>Electronic</genre>
 <album>Fireblue</album>
 <player>
    <song path="Fireblue.mp3"/>
    <song path="Porthole.mp3"/>
</player>
 </artist>
</Artists>
```

I want to retrieve all song path to add it in a ListBox like this :

```
XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load(path);
var q = from c in loaded.Descendants("player")
        select (string)c.Element("song path");
foreach (string track in q)
{
   myList.Items.Add(track);
}
```

But my program crash because the track string launch a SystemNullExceptionError. Can someone help me to retrieve properly the attribute :

> song path

from my XML file ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A MVVM styled approach would have you bind your ListBox directly to your XML document so that you don't have to set the contents of the ListBox in the back code.

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <XmlDataProvider Source="Artists.xml" XPath="/Artists/artist"/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=./name}" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=./player/song}" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@path}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>      
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List<string> songs = (from c in loaded.Descendants("song")
                    select c.Attribute("path").Value).ToList();
```

And also correct the XML by closing the `Artist` tag

Comment: Thanks, this answer is more accurate. Now I've a collection of my songs.

Comment: Ok thanks but if I've several artists, how to retrieve all songs for one artist based on his own ID ? where clause ?

Comment: Sure, use a where clause like this: var query = from c in loaded.Descendants("artist")
                        where c.Attribute("artistId").Value.Equals("2")
                        from s in c.Descendants("song")
                        select s;

Comment: You'r really helpfull thanks again, here is my final code : ` var query = from c in loaded.Descendants("artist")
                        where c.Attribute("Id").Value.Equals("1")
                        from s in c.Descendants("song")
                        select s.Attribute("path").Value.ToList();` But how to use query var in a foreach just to check my collection ? it doesn't work with this : `foreach(string track in query)
            {
                myList.Items.Add(track);
            }`

Answer (score 2):

- Your XML is wrong, you have not closed `<artist>` tag
- You are accessing element by name `"song path"` but you have only `song` element with attribute `path`

Query:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);

// type is IEnumerable<string>
var songs = xdoc.Descendants("song")                
                .Select(p => p.Attribute("path").Value);
```

Fixed XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Artists>
<artist artistId="1">
   <name>ManyBass</name>
   <genre>Electronic</genre>
   <album>Fireblue</album>
   <player>
       <song path="Fireblue.mp3"/>
       <song path="Porthole.mp3"/>
   </player>
</artist>
</Artists>
```

Comment: I just forget it but that's not the current problem.

Comment: the artist tag is added but I still have this problem.